# Write changing text to new pdf

Tags: python

I'm trying to open abc.pdf and find google.com and replace with input words. text changing but, I can write the new text to output.pdf it stay same with abc.pdf how can i solve this ?

```
import PyPDF2
import fitz
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
import requests

# # Replace with the URL of the PDF you want to download
# pdf_url = input("Enter the URL of the pdf file to download: ")
#
# # Replace with the link you want to replace the original links with
new_link = input("Enter the link you want to replace the original links with: ")
#
# # Download the PDF file
# response = requests.get(pdf_url)
# with open("abc.pdf", "wb") as f:
#     f.write(response.content)
with open('abc.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
    writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

    # pdf dosyasının tüm sayfalarını oku
    for page in range(len(reader.pages)):
        text = reader.pages[page].extract_text()
        print(text)
        # aranacak stringi bul
        if "google.com" in text:
            # stringi değiştir
            text = text.replace("google.com", new_link)
            # pdf dosyasını yeniden yaz
            print(text)
            writer.add_page(reader.pages[page])
            with open('output.pdf', 'wb') as output:
                writer.write(output)
file.close()
output.close()
```

I am also try with fitz, when I serach in links it has to be http:// so I couldnt change link like that google.com

```
import fitz
import requests

# Replace with the URL of the PDF you want to download
pdf_url = input("Enter the URL of the pdf file to download: ")

# Replace with the link you want to replace the original links with
new_link = input("Enter the link you want to replace the original links with: ")
old_link = input("Enter the link you want to replace  ")

# Download the PDF file
response = requests.get(pdf_url)
with open("file.pdf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(response.content)

# Open the PDF and modify the links
pdf_doc = fitz.open("file.pdf")
for page in pdf_doc:
    for link in page.links():
        print(link)
        if "uri" in link and link["uri"] == old_link:
            print("Found one")
            link["uri"] = new_link

# Save the modified PDF to the desktop
pdf_doc.save("test2.pdf")
pdf_doc.close()
```

And another :

```
import PyPDF2
import fitz
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
import requests

# # Replace with the URL of the PDF you want to download
# pdf_url = input("Enter the URL of the pdf file to download: ")
#
# # Replace with the link you want to replace the original links with
new_link = input("Enter the link you want to replace the original links with: ")
#
# # Download the PDF file
# response = requests.get(pdf_url)
# with open("abc.pdf", "wb") as f:
#     f.write(response.content)
# Open the original PDF file
# with open('abc.pdf', 'rb') as file:
doc = fitz.open('abc.pdf')
print(doc)
p = fitz.Point(50, 72)  # start point of 1st line

for page in doc:
    print(page)
    text = page.get_text()
    text = text.replace("google.com", new_link).encode("utf8")
    rc = page.insert_text(p,  # bottom-left of 1st char
                          text,  # the text (honors '\n')
                          fontname="helv",  # the default font
                          fontsize=11,  # the default font size
                          rotate=0,  # also available: 90, 180, 270
                          )    # print(text)
    # page.set_text(text)
    # doc.insert_pdf(text,to_page=0)
doc.save("output.pdf")
```

doc.close()

Comment: You are not using the full power of Fitz: https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

Comment: I also try with fitz but I couldnt, I added also fitz code

Comment: Is there any suggestion for me ?

Comment: I will be back online a little later and I will look at it again. Are there any error messages that get reported?